# Not able to generate public api token in judge.me shopify

Tags: shopify, remix.run, shopify-hydrogen

I have built website using [hydrogen shopify framework](https://hydrogen.shopify.dev/) and I want to integrate reviews using [judge.me](https://judge.me/) app. I am using this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@judgeme/shopify-hydrogen/v/2.0.0) to integrate.

It require public api token, which I am trying to generate by clicking on `show` but it is throwing an error "Something went wront, please try again"

I am currently using free version, is it because of this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is a bug related to the Shofiy dashboard. The support team informed me that you can now obtain the keys from here.

https://judge.me/settings?jump_to=judge.me+api